# Passing weights to lm and others within a function

Tags: r, function, syntax, lm

I have data as follows:

```
library(estimatr)
DF <- structure(list(country = c("C", "C", "C", "C", "J", "J", "B", 
"B", "F", "F"), year = c(2005, 2010, 2010, 2005, 2005, 2010, 
2010, 2005, 2010, 2005), sales= c(15.48, 12.39, 3.72, 23.61, 
4, 31.87, 25.33, 7.64, 0.26, 2.9), industry = c("D", "D", "E", 
"E", "F", "F", "F", "F", "D", "D"), urbanisation = c("B", "B", 
"A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "C", "C"), size = c(1, 1, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1), wt = c(14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 19L, 19L, 
30L, 30L, 20L, 20L), taxrate = c(12L, 14L, 14L, 12L, 21L, 18L, 
30L, 30L, 20L, 20L), vote = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1), 
    votewon = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am calling `lm` and `lm_robust` from within a function. The example was supposed to be a simplified version of a function I am using, where somehow, `lm` takes `weights=weights` as an argument and `lm_robust` fails when doing the same thing. Now when I tried to recreate the error, they both fail..

How am I supposed to pass the `weights` argument to this function?

```
lm_coll <- function (data=data, weights=weights) {

    a <- lm(sales~size+taxrate+industry, weights=weights, data=data)
    summary(a)
    b <- lm_robust(sales~size+taxrate+industry, weights=weights, data=data)
    summary(b)
}

lm_coll(DF, weights=wt)
```

Comment: `lm_coll(DF, weights=DF$wt)` should work for both.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Otto! Do you have any idea where the difference comes from and why? I would prefer to solve it inside the function instead of in the call of the function.

Comment: For now it does do the job though, thank you very much!

Comment: In the function definition you don't use the `data` argument; instead you use `DF` which likely is some global objects. The default values of your argument are global objects also and this is a bad practice: your function should just use their argument and not rely on global objects.

Comment: @nicola Thank you for your comment. The data/df issue was a typo/mistake. Corrected that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you want pass the weight column name as a string instead of referencing it with a `$` (as per my comment above). A simple way to accomplish this is to do:

```
lm_coll <- function (data, weight) {
    weights = data[,weight]

    a <- lm(sales~size+taxrate+industry, weights=weights, data=data)
    print(summary(a))
    b <- lm_robust(sales~size+taxrate+industry, weights=weights, data=data)
    print(summary(b))
}

lm_coll(data=DF, weight='wt')
```

The reason why your version fails, is that R is trying to find an object called `wt` from the local environment within `lm_coll`. Obviously that does not exist, because the environment only contains `DF` with a column called `wt`. My version of the function creates a new object called `weights` into the environment.

Comment: That is indeed a very easy fix, thank you very much!

Comment: With regard to your comment. The `data=DF` part was a typo (see Nicola's comment). I changed it in the question to `data=data`. Does your comment about the global environment still apply to the new situation?

Comment: Yes it does. `lm_coll <- function (data=data, weights=weights) ` just specifies default names for data and weights objects. That is, if you would run `lm_coll()` without any parameters, it would look for a data frame called data, and a weight vector called weight.